# Error when launching RDP Connection

Tags: java, applet, rdp

I access a company's VPN through a website and then click on a RDP link, this launches `properJavaRDP`, however after a minute or so it shows an alert with the following error message:

> Launching properJavaRDP session Connection Exception Connection Failed

I have the latest version of Java installed on my box and it works for other people so it's obviously a machine issue. 
It seems Cisco Software is the one launching the applet so it might be a Cisco related issue. Any ideas as to where to look at?

Comment: did u try checking few things like:  1. is remote machine up? 2. IS there any firewall/proxy issue? 3. Is the name entered correct with domain?